# @Font-Face Internet Explorer - Firefox same domain

Tags: font-face

I tried everything and i can't get working.

This is a part of my @font-face code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'font';
src: url('font-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('font-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('font-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('font-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('font-regular-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
url('font-regular-webfont.svg#font') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

It works in Chrome and Safari but don't works in IE and firefox. Fonts and css are in the same domain and i allways use relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all font formats are included in your IIS server environment. IIS does not include .woff by default. Confirm that EOT, TTF and SVG are there as well.

Comment: I added in HTTP Headers all mime-types is that correct?? Can u be a little bit more specific please.

Comment: Woff needs the MIME type 'application/x-font-woff'. Here's a page with some instructions: http://www.projectseven.com/tutorials/servers/iis-woff/index.htm

Comment: Now its working. I convert the font with your tool in base64 and EOT Lite and works fine in all browsers. Thanks for u wonderful tool. But I do too many request :D, and the app it's down now. Sorry, please fix it. Great-> http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator